# Excel: plot a column on a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got a column in excel with 450 values between 0 and 3000 and I'd like to plot it as points on a range from 0 to 4000, however, I'm unable to do so: the chart is misinterpreting what I want. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just right click the axis and *Format Axis...*  You didn't specify a version.

[image]